# How do I use my chrome profile using selenium with all webpages logged in?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, browser, selenium-chromedriver

This code below loads my chrome profile but my accounts are not logged in (my youtube is signed out after/while the code runs in the example below) on **Mac**.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import os

#create chromeoptions instance
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()


#provide location where chrome stores profiles
loc = os.path.expanduser("~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/")
options.add_argument(f"--user-data-dir={loc}")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/@MrBeast")

try:
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 2)
    # Do Something
    print('Task Completed')
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

My account is signed out from almost website when I open the browser after the code is executed. This is unexpected behaviour. How can I get rid of this?